# Is the following function convex or non convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

The function is:

$$f(X) = \frac{1}{a^H X a}$$
where, X is a complex hermitian symmetric matrix ($X = Y^H Y)$ and $a$ is a complex vector. Due to this fact, $a^H X a \in \mathbb{R}$. I am having difficulties finding the hessian of the function since the elements are complex.

Comment: What is the domain of definition? $\mathbb C^n \setminus\{0\}$ is not convex.

Comment: $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you define $f(0)=+\infty=\lim_{x\to0} f(x)$, which seems natural, then the resulting function is not convex. Let $e$ be a unit vector, then
$$
f(te) = \begin{cases} (e^HXe)^{-1} t^{-2} & \text{ if } t\ne 0\\ 
+\infty & \text{ if } t=0
\end{cases}
$$
is not convex as $f(0) > \frac12(f(e)+f(-e)$. So convexity fails already in the one-dimensional case. In addition, one can argue that $f$ is not convex for any other choice of $f(0)$.